# iOS Core data and unit test: multiple managed object context getting created

Tags: ios, unit-testing, core-data

I am pretty new to writing unit test cases for iOs application, In my application workflow(creating and editing a record) is working fine but when I call the method from test case following are observed:

1) **illegal attempt to establish a relationship between objects in different contexts**

2) setup and tear down are getting called after every test case.

I have checked the managed object context of both the entities and they are really different

**po [companyEntity managedObjectContext];**

NSManagedObjectContext: 0xcda9850

**(lldb) po [self managedObjectContext];**

NSManagedObjectContext: 0x10f2a0a0

Please help me to understand what probably can cause this.

Thanks
Ankit

Comment: You'll need to show how you are creating the managed object context.

Comment: You need to show us the code that is crashing. You need to show us the stack trace of the crash. Without those two pieces of information you are just going to get a lot of guesses.

Comment: I have a singelton database manager which creates the managedObjectContext and rest is standard process

Answer (score 1):

Clearly your singleton is either broken or you're creating multiple contexts.

Use stack logging to identify where the offending context is being created.

Add this argument to your run args in Xcode:

MallocStackLoggingNoCompact 1

These can be found in Schemes -> Run ****.app -> Environment Variables

```
$ sudo malloc_history [pid] [address]
```

i.e.
    $ sudo malloc_history 1234 0xcda9850
    $ sudo malloc_history 1234 0x10f2a0a0

Answer (score 0):

Actually singelton class which was part of multiple targets in there build phases -> compile sources thus getting compiled multiple times and thus causing  interference between the contexts.

I removed all the files apart from tests from test target and things worked fine.